# How do render nested array elements Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How to render nested array elements in React I want to get only one url in urlimgoutside array in   CardMedia .........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

[image]

```js
        {props.currentTodos.map((currentTodo) => (

                  <CardMedia
                    className={classes.cardMedia}
                    image = {currentTodo.urlimgoutside}
                  />

)}
```

this currentTodo

[image]

Comment: Please clear your code, and give us the part would be need to help

Comment: @KolaCaine  i clear my code done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the output you wanto to achieve... if you want one card for each URL, and supposing `urlimgoutside` is the array you're referring to:

```js
{props.currentTodos 
 ? props.currentTodos.map((currentTodo) =>
  currentTodo.urlimgoutside 
  ? currentTodo.urlimgoutside.map((url) =>
      <CardMedia className={classes.cardMedia}
                 image = {url}
      />
  : null
  ))
 :null
}
```

Comment: i use it show error ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: That's because I'm supposing `urlimgoutside` is an array and apparently it's not. You need to provide more info about `currentTodo` object and what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: i upload currentTodo array console picture  done @julianobrasil

Comment: Apparently it's just a matter of protecting the code against falsey values.... I've updated my code. But I still don't know if you wanna see one card per image.